# Rails 3 jquery in js.erb template is creating escaped html?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, I've got an update.js.erb template with one simple line of jquery:

```
$("#some_div").html("<strong>some_content</strong>");
```

Upon form submission, all the ajaxy stuff is working fine, but the content in #some_div is being replaced with "`<strong>some_content</strong>`" instead of **some_content**. Does anyone have a clue why?

This was working fine in Rails 2. Thanks in advance for the help.

**Update (semi-solved):**Stupid me, still had jquery.form plugin hanging around, which doesn't magically play well.  Looks like I'll be ripping some stuff apart again ... thanks for the help, folks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Are you using `.html()` or `.text()`?  Also are you sure the content is not encoded coming back, e.g. `&lt;strong&gt;` and not `<strong>`?

Comment: Definitely using .html() ... the content may be coming back encoded, but I think that's due to the Rails 3 magic that I clearly am not fully understanding. I've got my jquery.rails.js file and my <%= csrf_meta_tag %> helper in place, etc. but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on jQuery 1.4, please try,

```
$('#some_div').html(function(i,v){
    return $('<strong>').html('some_content');
});
```

( p.s. I like single quotes on javascript )

Comment: Thanks Reigel ... I think my problem is due to some Rails 3 encoding /safe string magic that I don't get.  Your code gave me an error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &lt;strong&gt;

Comment: @jonphillips - That's *definitely* rails encoding it, not a client-side issue...need to figure out why it's encoding the script.